# Angular (4) 404 on page refresh after adding CLI

Tags: apache, angular, url-rewriting, router, apache-config

I have an angular app and I have recently added CLI to make things easier. Everything works fine as before except page refresh. If I browse from index page, app works fine but if I try to refresh the page or paste url in browser it returns 404 error.

I have redirected all the urls that I am using to Index page on server and have added base "/" tag in index page.

Apache config httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot <path to dir in wwwroot>
    ServerName e3edge-staging.localhost
    <Directory path_to_dir_in_wwwroot>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine  on
        RewriteRule    "^/team(/.*)*$"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/myraters(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/myreports(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/help(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/team(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/login(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/rater(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/audios(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/videos(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/assessment(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/attachments(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/home$"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/myprofile$"  "/index.html"  [PT]
        RewriteRule    "^/profile(/.*)*"  "/index.html"  [PT]
    # Other directives here
    # ExpiresActive On
    # ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
</VirtualHost>
```

Index.html

```
<head> 
<base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>e3edge</title>
...
```

Every one seems to be suggesting this same solution that I already have in place but it doesn't seem to work for me. It does work when in dev mode (ng serve) in localhost.

can any one please suggest what could be wrong here.

Many Thanks

Comment: change <base href="/"> to `<base href=".">`

Comment: Your question is more an apache question than an angular one. You should tag it with apache

Comment: @Parth <base href="."> didn't work for me

Comment: reason that I think its something in angular/cli is because redirect was working before I added cli

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302373/deploy-angular-4-app-on-apache-webserver/59942239#59942239