# Deploy Angular 4 App on Apache Webserver

Tags: angular, apache, centos7

I want to deploy my Angular Application on my Apache Webserver. I already added a `.htaccess` file to my `/var/www/html` folder, I tried several base-hrefs. But like many people I have problems with routing. I can only see my Startpage, but when I want to get to a other URL it fails. What else can I try or have I missed something?

Comment: Try to add hashed to your url pattern. It looks like your setup of your server is not correct. https://angular.io/guide/router#browser-url-styles

Comment: @Taha Obed, can we have a chat, I am trying to do same thing, like I want to deploy Angular 4 application on apache server, and I want to know the nitty gritty involved, my gmail is theakshay.jain@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable/install the Apache `mod_rewrite` module, and then put this in either your `.htaccess` or your apache configuration for your site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Installing and enabling mod_rewrite fixed the problem! :)

Comment: @PierreDuc, can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47315228/2761641

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line at "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

To

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so