# Angular 6 build, Error 404 Not Found when refresh page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have facing a problem **404 page not found** in production build when refresh a page.
Build working fine with `#` routing `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`. But I want a pretty route without `#`

My module look like

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Which web server you are using for production build deployment?

Comment: Now I'm testing on Apache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302373/deploy-angular-4-app-on-apache-webserver/59942239#59942239

Comment: try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302373/deploy-angular-4-app-on-apache-webserver/59942239#59942239

Comment: here is simple article to fix this issue https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/14/how-to-fix-404-page-not-found-error-after-build-in-angular-or-react-or-vue-js/

Answer (score 13):

The reason why **404 Not Found** is showing on page refresh is that all Angular routes should be served via the index.html file.

You can fix this issue by adding a .htaccess file (in the same directory where the index.html resides) with the following contents.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Follow below link for further details regarding **deploying production build to Apache**:

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2

Comment: I am trying to deploy a single-page Angular 6 app to a SharePoint. I keep having the same issue that the original poster had. I tried your solution but did not change the results.

Comment: This solution is for apache web server, not for SharePoint

Answer (score 6):

Create **.htaccess** file in your index.html location

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /example/example/
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Note:RewriteBase /example/example is a your index.html base url

`<base href="/example/example/">`

Answer (score 3):

For **Apache**

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

For **Nginx**

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

For **IIS**

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

For **GitHub pages**

```
you can't directly configure the GitHub Pages server, but you can add a 404 page. Copy index.html into 404.html. It will still be served as the 404 response, but the browser will process that page and load the app properly. It's also a good idea to serve from docs/ on master and to create a .nojekyll file
```

For **Firebase Hosting**

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

[Source](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Deep urls are called SPA support, by default node's http-server doesn't support, but it can be enabled this way-

```
http-server --gzip --proxy http://localhost:8080?
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling rewrite module should solve this problem.

**For Ubuntu Apache2 configuration -**

```sh
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**For CentOs Apache Httpd configuration -**

```sh
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Look for

```sh
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and remove the # sign at its beginning, to enable mod_rewrite

```sh
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If # is not present at the beginning, it means mod_rewrite is already enabled
If you don’t find the above line, just add it to the file

```sh
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```